# Norm of an operator in $\ell^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

We define the operator: $l^p$ to $l^p$ with the $p$-norm

$T( (a_{n} ))= a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ So its like:

$(a_1,a_2,a_3.....)$ goes to $(a_2-a_1,a_3-a_2....)$

They re asking me about the norm of the operator, first I see that $|| (1,0,0,0...) ||_p=1$ and $|| T((1,0,0..)=1 ||_p$ so the norm is more or equal than 1. But for proving that the norm is less or equal than 1 I have a problem, because $|| a_{n+1}-a_{n} ||_p$ I can see for triangle inequality that is less or equal than 2 but not that 1. Thank you

Comment: Think about the sequence $x_1=(1,0,0,\ldots), x_{2} =(1,-1,0,0,\ldots), x_{3}=(1,-1,1,0,0,\ldots),\ldots$. What do you get?

Comment: This sequence doesnt have norm less or equal than 1 for every n, for n=2 the norm is 2^(1/p)

Comment: Dear user Energy, the norm of an operator is $\sup ||Tx||/||x||$, there is no problem if the norm of the elements in the sequence is greater than 1, you can always divide by $||x||$.

Comment: Thanks, I was using another definition of norm, I know both are equivalent, but for proving that it could be more complicated, with this definition it everything correct now :)

Answer (score 1):

Define $a_n:=c^n$ where $\left|c\right|\lt 1$. Then $\left|a_{n+1}-a_n\right|^p=c^{np}\left|c-1\right|^p=a_n^p\left|c-1\right|^p$, which gives that $\left\lVert T\left(\left(a_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}\right)\right\rVert =\left|c-1\right|\left\lVert\left(a_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}\right\rVert  $. We thus obtain that $\lVert T\rVert\geqslant\left|c-1\right| $ for each $c\in (-1,1)$. Now let $c\to -1$ to get the result.